# How do I selectively display a Chrome Extension's toolbar icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a background page. The background.js script only correctly operates on certain sites (as intended). How do I hide the icon in the google chrome toolbar on sites where it isn't used? Preferably only displaying the icon on sites defined in the manifest as permissible.

I am trying to use pageActions, this is my current non-functioning code. No icon is shown.

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Called when the url of a tab changes.
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
// If the tabs url starts with "http://specificsite.com"...
if (tab.url.indexOf('http://') == 0) {
// ... show the page action.
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

The manifest:

```
  "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "key.png",
        "default_title": "Download this Deck"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

**EDIT:** It seems to work after I reload the extension until I switch tabs with the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific API to match your case, [declarativeContent API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent).

The one and only possible action currently implemented is to show the Page Action button based on a set of rules. See the documentation for more extensive examples.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  var rule = {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { hostSuffix: 'example.com' },
      })
    ],
    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
  };

  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute some action like with browserAction? I had chrome.browserAction.onClicked executing "code: download()" when it was clicked, but it seems to not work with pageAction? Can I avoid using a popup.html?

Comment: What do you mean? `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` is there and should work. And no, this API can only serve to show the Page Action currently.

Comment: Actually it seems I can't execute the function "download();" from my background.js anymore, but it worked when it was a browserAction? What gives? "download();" is a function in one of my content scripts that runs on specific pages, but it doesn't seem to work when ran through pageAction on those pages.

Comment: No idea not knowing your manifest and the function. Check that you have host permissions and/or activeTab permission. And _debug_. Use Dev Tools on your background page.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a page action for this instead of a browser action.
It's designed specifically for what you're asking for.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction

Comment: I can't for the life of me get this to work... edited OP with my code, perhaps you could help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible anymore using the declarativeContent as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69847401/6908282)

> Unfortunately this isn't possible (anymore). Declarative content or not, the presence of your extension's icon near the address bar is only decided by the user by pinning/unpinning it from the extension menu. In older versions of Chrome using chrome.pageAction would result in the extension icon being shown inside the address bar only for the matching websites declared in the manifest. However, things changed a while ago...