# Show or Hide Extension Icon based on Current Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, visibility

Is there a way to show/hide a chrome extension's icon based on the current tab's URL/location?

I'm writing a utility that I only want to use on certain sites, and I would like to be able to access it in one click while on those sites (i.e. not in the extension overflow menu) but hide it otherwise.

The [DeclarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeContent/) API *almost* provides what I'm looking for, but it only greys out the icon, rather than hiding it entirely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible (anymore). Declarative content or not, the presence of your extension's icon near the address bar is only decided by the user by pinning/unpinning it from the extension menu. In older versions of Chrome using `chrome.pageAction` would result in the extension icon being shown inside the address bar only for the matching websites declared in the manifest. However, things changed a while ago (actually quite some time, maybe >1y, can't recall exactly when): now all extension icons are on the right side outside the address bar and can be pinned/unpinned by the user, meaning they are either always shown or never shown. Pinned icons that use `pageAction` are greyed out when inactive (see [this documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageAction/)).

Comment: That sucks, but I suppose it makes sense. I suppose it has at least something to do with users not appreciating icons showing up and disappearing outside of their control. Just sucks that for people that actually _want_ that functionality, it's not an option. Thanks for the quick response!